# Create PostgreSQL view to feed a chart generating tool having filter option

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-view

We need to create a postgres SQL view to generate a chart. Chart creating tool allow only a single SQL view as input. The chart has the filter option by studentname, cousecode and feecode. Other than the chart display, we need to show the sum of the total course fee and fee amount paid by all the students from the same view.

```
table1: student
id  name    address
1   John    USA
2   Robert  UK
3   Tinger  NZ
```

```
table2: student_course

id  std_id  coursecode  fee
1   1       CHEM        3000 
2   1       PHY         4000
3.  1       BIO         2000
4.  2       CHEM        3000
5.  2       GEO         1500
6.  3       ENG         2000
```

```
table3: student_fees
id  std_name    coursecode  feecode     amount
1   1           CHEM        BKFEE       100
2   1           CHEM        SPFEE       140
3   1           CHEM        MATFEE      250
4   1           PHY         BKFEE       150
5   1           PHY         SPFEE       200
6   1           BIO         LBFEE       300
7   1           BIO         MATFEE      350
9   1           BIO         TECFEE      200
10  2           CHEM        BKFEE       100
11  2           CHEM        SPFEE       140
12  2           GEO         BKFEE       150
13  3           ENG         BKFEE       75
14  3           ENG         SPFEE       140
15  3           ENG         LBFEE       180
```

Am able to create a view like this. But this view is not enough for my operation. Because from this view I couldn't calculate the sum of the total course fee(course fee is repeating). In this case, the grouping will not work. Because of the need to filter the data by studentname,coursecode and feecode.

```
View: 

id  std_id  coursecode  course_fee  feecode     fee_amount
1   John    CHEM        3000        BKFEE       100
2   John    CHEM        3000        SPFEE       140
3   John    CHEM        3000        MATFEE      250
4   John    PHY         4000        BKFEE       150
5   John    PHY         4000        SPFEE       200
6   John    BIO         4000        LBFEE       300
7   John    BIO         4000        MATFEE      350
8   John    BIO         4000        TECFEE      200
9   Robert  CHEM        3000        BKFEE       100
10  Robert  CHEM        3000        SPFEE       140
11  Robert  GEO         1500        BKFEE       150
12  Tinger  ENG         2000        BKFEE       75
13  Tinger  ENG         2000        SPFEE       140
14  Tinger  ENG         2000        LBFEE       180
```

So in any way can we create a view like this ?

```
View: 
id  std_id  coursecode  course_fee  feecode     fee_amount
1   John    CHEM        3000        BKFEE       100
2   John    CHEM        0           SPFEE       140
3   John    CHEM        0           MATFEE      250
4   John    PHY         4000        BKFEE       150
5   John    PHY         0           SPFEE       200
6   John    BIO         4000        LBFEE       300
7   John    BIO         0           MATFEE      350
8   John    BIO         0           TECFEE      200
9   Robert  CHEM        3000        BKFEE       100
10  Robert  CHEM        0           SPFEE       140
11  Robert  GEO         1500        BKFEE       150
12  Tinger  ENG         2000        BKFEE       75
13  Tinger  ENG         0           SPFEE       140
14  Tinger  ENG         0           LBFEE       180
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for rollup functionality in your view query i am shearing you 2 links fist one is for the basics how rollup works and the 2nd one is specific to Postgresql
[first link](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-rollup/) , [second link](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rollup/) Hope this will help you

I have work out one demo for you please check [rollup query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8e1b9/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

Not similar to the answer you are expecting but you can explore **GROUPING SET**

```
select name, sf.coursecode, amount, sum(fee)
from student s, student_course sc, student_fees sf
where s.id = sc.std_id
and sf.std_name = s.id
and sf.coursecode = sc.coursecode
group by 
        GROUPING SETS (
        (name, sf.coursecode, amount, fee),
        (name, sf.coursecode, fee),
        ()
    )
order by name, sf.coursecode asc
```